# Block all traffic except web proxy

Tags: linux, openwrt

My goal is to make Firefox on Windows access the internet via a web proxy that is on some hardware. I want to block Windows from accessing microsoft services and asking me things. My school had such a proxy on Windows machines and it worked very well, but I'm stuck configuring OpenWRT to get the same setup.

I have configured the uplink via my WLAN and I have installed polipo. Privoxy was too big for the somewhat old router.

Polipo now is doing what it should, but I'm stuck at the important part where I want to block all traffic that is not for the webclient, ssh and polipo. I mean, when the Windows machine is plugged into the router, it should not be able to access the internet without knowing the port number of the web proxy.

What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by configuring it in LEDE / Network / Firewall / Tab "Traffic Rules" / small Text "New forward rule:".

**1)**
I made a new rule with these changes:

```
Source zone: Any zone 
Destination zone: Input
Destination port: 8123 (polipo's default port)
```

so that it will appear in this rules list with this "Match" text:

```
Any traffic
From any host in any zone
To any router IP at port 8123 on this device
```

**2)**
Then in the
*tab "General Settings" at "Zones" in the zone forwarding **"lan => wan rule"***
I changed input from "accept" to "reject".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).